# Wordpress Custom Search for custom post type - display the result by its category and tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom search through search.php
How could I search the post by its category and tag?

can anyone help me how could I display the search result through this dropdown category ang tag

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
<input type="search" name="s">
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( ); ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=post_tag',); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I like to display the result and its total number.
and if no post yet or result, it will display the "no result for the (result category and tag name)"

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom search through search.php in WordPress and allow users to search for posts by category and tag, you can modify your code as follows:

1. Create a custom search form in your search.php template with
   dropdowns for category and tag selection:

```
    <form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
        <input type="search" name="s">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' => 'All Categories',  // Display "All Categories" as the default option
            'name' => 'cat'  // This sets the 'cat' query parameter for category filtering
        )); ?>
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' => 'All Tags',  // Display "All Tags" as the default option
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',  // Specify the taxonomy as 'post_tag'
            'name' => 'tag'  // This sets the 'tag' query parameter for tag filtering
        )); ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

2. In your search.php file, process the search query and display the results. You can use the pre_get_posts action to modify the main query before it's executed:

```
    <?php
    get_header();
    ?>
    
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    
            <?php
            // Check if there's a search query
            if (have_posts()) {
                $search_query = get_search_query();
    
                // Display the search query
                echo "<h1>Search Results for: $search_query</h1>";
    
                // Display the selected category and tag (if any)
                $selected_category = get_category(intval($_GET['cat']));
                $selected_tag = get_term_by('id', intval($_GET['tag']), 'post_tag');
    
                if ($selected_category) {
                    echo "<p>Category: " . $selected_category->name . "</p>";
                }
    
                if ($selected_tag) {
                    echo "<p>Tag: " . $selected_tag->name . "</p>";
                }
    
                // Display the total number of search results
                echo "<p>Total Results: " . $wp_query->found_posts . " posts</p>";
    
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    // Display your post content as you normally would
                    the_title();
                    the_content();
                endwhile;
    
            } else {
                // No results found
                echo "<h1>No results found for your search.</h1>";
                // Optionally, you can display the selected category and tag (if any)
                if ($selected_category) {
                    echo "<p>Category: " . $selected_category->name . "</p>";
                }
                if ($selected_tag) {
                    echo "<p>Tag: " . $selected_tag->name . "</p>";
                }
            }
            ?>
    
        </main>
    </div>
    
    <?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

This code will display the search results along with the selected category and tag, as well as the total number of search results. If no results are found, it will display a message indicating that no results were found for the specified category and tag (if any).

Comment: HI thank you, it's really helpful. however tag is not working. every time I search with tag, the result is not found. even I search tag only still the result is not found. also the  echo "<p>Tag: " . $selected_tag->name . "</p>"; is not displaying.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Just want to double check, have you assigned any tags to your existing posts?

Comment: hi, thank you for keep me helping. about with your question if I already assigned a tag in my existing post? my answer is YES. I have 7 existing tags, and 7 categories and I used each of them to existing post so I can check if each of categories and tags are working.